# Using geometry instead of geography

Tags: postgis, geometry-conversion, st-dwithin

I have a basic query to run with PostGIS: research all LINESTRINGs close to my centre within a radius. "Linestring" is the only geometry used and represented by two points with longitude and latitude degrees.

I am able to do a Geography - spherical - based query but not a Geometry  - Euclidean - based one.

The subject must be obviously solved, so if any reader could guide me to where to find some answers.

- Geography setting works

With type "GEOGRAPHY", things are easy and the coordinates are easily understandable. I build the table "events" of interest with this migration:

```
ALTER TABLE events ADD COLUMN coordinates geography (LINESTRING);
CREATE INDEX  events_gix ON events USING GIST(coordinates);
```

The query below works:

```sql
SELECT events.id, events.coordinates,...
FROM events
WHERE ST_DWithin(ST_MakePoint($1, $2), events.coordinates, $3, false);
```

where the values `$1,$2,$3` are respectively the LNG/LAT of the centre and the radius (in meters), and where I use `use_spheroid=false`.

I understand the `<->`operator along with a GIST index accelerates the query, so it can be reformulated as:

```sql
SELECT events.id, events.coordinates...
FROM events
WHERE events.coordinates  <-> ST_MakePoint($1,$2) < $3;
```

I am not sure if this is more performant.

Since all my data are local - but could be "almost" anywhere on the globe - I want to use the Euclidean approximation to make it run faster, so I should use the type Geometry instead.

- Geometry setting

I start with the migration:

```
SELECT AddGeometryColumn ('events', 'coordinates', 4326, 'LINESTRING', 2, false);
```

but:

- I need to change the centre point from LNG/LAT into projected coordinates. But I see that there are many possible projections  (https://epsg.io/). Which one to choose? Stick to 4326? I wasn't able to cast this: tried different casting methods, but I can't use variables in `'SRID=4326,POINT($1 $2)'::geometry` as I get "could not determine the data type of parameter $1",  and even I can pass the variables in  `ST_Makepoint($1,$2,4326)::geometry`, the function `ST_DWithin` between the centre and a linestring returns an error.
- I also need to convert the radius from meters to degrees if I understood correctly but didn't find which function to use.

```sql
SELECT events.id, events.coordinates,...
FROM events
WHERE ST_DWithin(ST_MakePoint($1, $2, 4326)::geometry, events.coordinates, $3, false);
```

then I get:

```
Operation on mixed SRID geometries (LineString, 4326) != (Point, 0)
```

Comment: the last query will automatically cast to `geography` by the way... so... is it really slow? if not, just stick with `geography`, else you would have to find a suitable local coordinate system that preserve distances, and have lots of fun if you need multiple ones.

Comment: No, it isn't slow, <50ms but I tested only 3 clusters of 100 points so I was wondering. I am happy to stick to Geography.  Then is it better to use `<->` or `DWithin ...false`?

Comment: `ST_DWithin` does a bounding box comparison first, using the spatial index, so it should be (much) faster as you wouldn't be computing distances between every features in your dataset. Consider `<->` if you need to order your result by distance (after `st_dwithin`)

Comment: Very clear answer. Thks.